# How to copy image data into a subclass of BufferedImage?

Tags: java, graphics, copy, bufferedimage

I have a class called Bitmap which extends from BufferedImage,

```
public class Bitmap extends BufferedImage {...
```

One of its methods called copyImage, which copies contents from a source image into   the class, it worked but this method doesn't maintain the original aspect ratio and dimensions of the source image.

```
public void copyImage(Image image) {
    if (image != null) {
        BufferedImage bi = (BufferedImage) image;
        Graphics g = getGraphics();

        g.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, width, height, null);
    }
}
```

I want this method to copy the source image to the class with its original aspect ratio and dimensions maintained, I thought of resizing an width and height I modified the code above to this:

```
public void copyImage(Image image) {
    if (image != null) {
        this.width = image.getWidth(null);
        this.height = image.getWidth(null);

        BufferedImage bi = (BufferedImage) image;
        Graphics g = getGraphics();

        g.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, width, height, null);
    }
}
```

But it didn't work, how can I modify the code above to copy the image?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I want to use BufferedImage for a pixel drawing panel for my project. I added few methods to BufferedImage like putPixel(Int x, int y, Color color) and getPixels(). It's for flexibility.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels What does "copying an image" means anyway? Is drawing contents of the source image to the destination image a way to copy?

Comment: Also note that this `BufferedImage bi = (BufferedImage) image;` creates a new variable but not a new object as it simply references the parameter, and is a dangerous cast -- what if the image parameter **isn't** a BufferedImage but is some other type of Image? Again your code looks very confusing to me.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels You misunderstood, Graphics g = getGraphics(); not Graphics g = bi.getGraphics(); So I did not draw image to itself, I want to draw image to the class.

Comment: Ah, you are correct, and I am at fault. My apologies and thank you for clarifying -- so you're drawing the image in it's not maintaining its aspect ratio -- are you trying to resize it so that it fits into the current image?

Comment: Then this is in error: `this.height = image.getWidth(null);`. It should be `this.height = image.getHeight(null);`

Comment: There are also other overloads of the `drawImage(...)` method that would help if you also want to re-size it

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I want the copyImage method to copy contents of the inputted image to the class while maintaining the inputted image's original aspect ratio and dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in error:

```
public void copyImage(Image image) {
    if (image != null) {
        this.width = image.getWidth(null);
        this.height = image.getWidth(null);

        BufferedImage bi = (BufferedImage) image;
        Graphics g = getGraphics();

        g.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, width, height, null);
    }
}
```

Your main problems are:

1. You appear to be trying to change the intrinsic width and height of the original image, the `this` image, and you shouldn't do this, not this way
2. You are assigning the parameter image's width to the `this.height` field with `this.height = image.getWidth(null);`

Other issues:

- You're not conserving resources
- You're making a dangerous and unnecessary cast

and it should be

```
public void copyImage(Image image) {
    if (image != null) {
        // don't change the width/height of your original image
        int width = image.getWidth(null);
        // int height = image.getWidth(null);
        int height = image.getHeight(null); // *** Note change ***

        // BufferedImage bi = (BufferedImage) image;  // *** no need ***
        Graphics g = getGraphics();

        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height, null);
        g.dispose();  // save resources
    }
}
```

Test code using a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing proof of concept:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TestImage {
    public static final String SOMME_PATH = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/"
            + "wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/Cheshire_Regiment_trench_Somme_1916.jpg"
            + "/1024px-Cheshire_Regiment_trench_Somme_1916.jpg";
    public static final String BATTLE_PATH = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/"
            + "commons/1/13/K%C3%A4mpfe_auf_dem_Doberdo.JPG";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int imgW = 1000;
        int imgH = 700;
        MyImage myImage = new MyImage(imgW, imgH, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        BufferedImage sommeTrench = null;
        BufferedImage battleOfDoberdò = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(SOMME_PATH);
            sommeTrench = ImageIO.read(url);

            url = new URL(BATTLE_PATH);
            battleOfDoberdò = ImageIO.read(url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        Icon icon = new ImageIcon(myImage);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, icon, "Original MyImage", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

        myImage.copyImage(sommeTrench);
        icon = new ImageIcon(myImage);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, icon, "MyImage with Somme Trench", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

        myImage.copyImage(battleOfDoberdò);        
        icon = new ImageIcon(myImage);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, icon, "MyImage with Battle Of Doberdò", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

    }
}
```

```
class MyImage extends BufferedImage {

    public MyImage(int width, int height, int imageType) {
        super(width, height, imageType);
    }

    public void copyImage(Image image) {
        if (image != null) {
            int width = image.getWidth(null);

            int height = image.getHeight(null); // *** Note change ***

            Graphics g = getGraphics();

            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height, null);
            g.dispose(); // save resources
        }
    }    
}
```

If you run this code you will see 3 images displaying as ImageIcons within 3 JOptionPanes, the first the original blank MyImage object, and then after 2 images from World War I have been copied into the original image.

Comment: Nice answer but it didn't work, I did not get what I expected, have you tested your code?

Comment: @user123456789: testing it now with **my** code, but I can't with yours, not without a [mcve] post. Hang on...

Comment: @user123456789: OK, yes, now I've tested my code for proof of concept in a valid [mcve], and have proven that it works. To prove it to yourself, copy my classes into your IDE and run them. They can all be copied into a single file called TestImage.java. You will see 3 JOptionPanes, the first showing the original myImage that is blank, then after 2 images have been copied into it.